# Tensorflow: execute computations and avoid memory exceeded

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I try to compute tensorflow task for data size `(624003, 17424)`, that was getting from text using `CountVectorizer`.

I always get an error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized`

But if I use sample of data like `(213556, 11605)` sample it works well.
But after increasing size of dataset it fail.

I try to use this code for tensorflow

```
batch_size = 1024

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, X_train.shape[1]), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, y_train.shape[1]), name="y")

# set model weights
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([X_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[1]], stddev=0.5), name="weights")

# construct model
y_pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, weights))

# minimize error using cross entropy
# cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(y_pred), reduction_indices=1))
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-(y*tf.log(y_pred) + (1 - y)*tf.log(1 - y_pred)))

optimizer_01 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)
optimizer_001 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

# saving model weights
saver = tf.train.Saver({"weights": weights})

# variables initializing
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# starting session
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
```

And in main block I train on train data and get acc of test data.

How can I learn on all train data and avoid memory exceeded?

For batch I use next function

```
def optimize(session, optimizer, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, epoch=1):
    for epoch in range(epoch):
        for batch_i, (start, end) in enumerate(split(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size)):
            x_batch, y_true_batch, = X_train[start:end].toarray(), y_train[start:end]
            feed_dict_train = {X: x_batch, y: y_true_batch}
            session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

        feed_dict_test = {X: X_test.toarray(), y: y_test}
        cost_step_test = session.run(cost, feed_dict={X: X_test.toarray(), y: y_test})
```

Answer (score 0):

(624003, 17424) Tensor is about 40GBytes. So you shouldn't allocate such a big Tensor.
You need to give up full-batch training, and switch to mini-batch training.

Comment: But I use batch with 1024 size. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: I've added func to batch